# Appending multiple rows in a loop to an out parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I need to take a backup of all the records that will be deleted by the following code. For that, I am trying to replace all the delete commands with `select *` and save it to a file using jdbc ResultSet  but I am stuck at the below snippet wherein records are being marked and then deleted in a loop. I have tried expanding this logic using `select..in and...exist` statements but the query is taking way too long to process and might fail in production. I also tried using `sys_refcursor` but the problem is that the `delete` is inside a loop and a cursor cannot be updated. So, the basic requirement is how can I store all the records being deleted by the following code in a out_parameter and return it. Please help! Thanks.

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR purger(p_reference IN VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT DISTINCT id, reference, PARENT, LEVEL
        FROM table ps1
        START WITH ps1.reference = p_reference
        CONNECT BY PRIOR ps1.reference = ps1.parent;
BEGIN
FOR i IN (SELECT DISTINCT reference
                FROM table
                WHERE PARENT IS NULL)
      LOOP
        l_level  := 'N';
        FOR j IN purger(i.reference)
        LOOP
          IF j.level > 1
          THEN
            l_level := 'Y';
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
        IF l_level = 'N'
        THEN
          DELETE FROM tale WHERE reference = i.reference;
        END IF;
        IF l_level = 'Y'
        THEN
          DELETE FROM table
          WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
                       FROM table ps1
                       START WITH ps1.reference = i.reference
                       CONNECT BY PRIOR ps1.reference = ps1.parent);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a trigger for the table(s) where the records are being deleted? The ON DELETE trigger could first insert the records that are about to be deleted into a separate table.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to time and process constraints making any db side change is currently impossible. So I am trying to convert this delete query into a select query and run it in an anonymous block.

Comment: I just need help in converting this loop into a select query.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a collection of your primary keys. Whenever you delete row(s) store list of id in temp collection. Add its elements to main collection. After all deletes main collection has all primary key values, which were deleted. You can return this collection, rollback and show rows. Hope this helps.

Test data:

```
create table test (id, col) as 
  select 1, 'P' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Q' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Z' from dual;
```

Code block:

```
declare 
  va sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  vb sys.odcinumberlist;
begin
  -- first delete
  delete from test where col in ('Z') returning id bulk collect into vb;
  -- add deleted ids to VA
  for i in 1..vb.count loop va.extend; va(va.last) := vb(i); end loop;

  -- second delete
  delete from test where col in ('P', 'Z') returning id bulk collect into vb;
  -- add deleted ids to VA
  for i in 1..vb.count loop va.extend; va(va.last) := vb(i); end loop;

  -- variable VA has all deleted ids
  -- you can rollback and show deleted rows if you want

  rollback;
  for rec in (select * from test where id in (select * from table(va))) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.id||' '||rec.col);
  end loop;
end;
```